# How to mock the router.navigate method in jest

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I am a beginner in unit testing using Jest in Angular. In my component, I have the `this.router.navigate()` method. Earlier I was using Jasmine to test it. For that I had done the following:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

Then,

```
let router:Router;
```

Then, in the `beforeEach`,

```
router = TestBed.get(Router);
```

Then, in the testcase,

```
it('should show news intially ', () => {
   const navigateSpy = spyOn(router,'navigate');
   component.showNews();
   expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/news']);
 });
```

This test was passed. But how do I do the same using Jest? Please Help.

I have an `ngOnInit()` method which calls another method `getDynamicMenus()`. Below is the `ngOnInit()` method:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getDynamicMenus();
  }


  getDynamicMenus() {
    this.menuService.getAllMenus().subscribe(menus => {
      this.menus = menus._embedded.menu;
    });
  }
```

Please let me know how to mock this method. In jasmine, I mocked the `getDynamicMenus()` and called `component.ngOnInit()`. But this doesn't work in Jest. Please help.

Comment: `jest.spyOn(router, 'navigate').mockReturnValue(null);` and then `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/news']);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent of the jasmine `spyOn()` function is [jest.spyOn(object, methodName)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname).

```js
it('should show news intially ', () => {
   const navigateSpy = jest.spyOn(router,'navigate');
   component.showNews();
   expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/news']);
});
```